# Connecting vmware on two computers

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, switch, linux-networking

I have a switch and 2 computers, each one has vmware with a running centos 5.8 on.
what i am trying to do is ping centos2 from centos 1 through the switch(10\100).
please help.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how your networking is setup on the host(s).

The easiest way would be to use bridged mode, this would allow the host to share the network adapter with the guest, giving the guest direct access to your LAN. Think of this as turning the host NIC into a switch, and having one cable going to the host, with others going to the guests.

With a bridged interface, you should only need to assign them IP's, netmask, and gateway the same as you would for a physical machine.

If you are using NAT, you are pretty much using the NIC as a router instead of a switch. This means you would need to set up routing on the host in order to make the connections. You would need to create forwarding rules that move packets from the guest subnet to the outside, and back. You would also need to set your host OS as the default gateway on each guest.

With NAT, I would advise you to keep IP addressing schemes separate to avoid confusion.

So please provide us with more details for a more descriptive answer. Bridged mode is by far going to be the easiest to accomplish what you want, providing there are no other circumstances preventing this.